# Grammaticality of "the near-term pain a trade battle would impose on U.S. workers will prove worthwhile"

Tags: grammaticality, commas, syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences

In the last August edition of *TIME* Magazine, I stumbled across this sentence. I am not a native speaker and am interested whether the unusual structure without any comma is correct. I am also unsure about the meaning of the word *impose* in this context.

> But there's a catch for the Trump team. If you want to be sure **the near-term pain a trade battle would impose on U.S. workers will prove worthwhile** in the long run, you'd better have allies — both political and military.

Comment: *A trade battle would impose on US workers the near-term pain which  will prove worthwhile in the long run. If you want to make sure this,  you must have both political and military  allies.*

Answer (score -1):

“the near-term pain a trade battle would impose on U.S. workers will prove worthwhile...”

Can be rewritten as “the pain that a trade battle would put on US workers will be worth it.”

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please provide support for your answer. I do not think "put on pain" (not a direct quote) is correct or idiomatic English.